# Performance issue with C# if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I do have below function which taking more time for execution can someone help  to write it properly,its getting while importing data  for validation purpose

```
public void MapReferences(Company company, ISession session, List<Contract> contracts, List<Employee> employees, List<CompanySettingsMap> companies, List<Contact> contacts, IList<ImportEmployeeOrgProfileBatchItem> importedOrgProfileData, int lineNum = 2)
{
    var dateConvertor = new DateConverter();

    DateTime date;
    foreach (var item in importedOrgProfileData)
    {
        item.CompanyId = company.Id;
        item.LineNumber = lineNum;
        item.CompanyReference = company?.Reference;

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Contact contact = new Contact();

        #region " Organisation Validation"  
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Organisation))
        {
            item.CanContinue = false;
            item.ErrorsList.Add("Invalid Organisation");
        }
        else
        {
            var allcontact = contacts.Where(x => x.Company.Id == company.Id && x.Reference.ToLower() == item.Organisation.ToLower()).ToList();

            if (allcontact.Count > 1)
            {
                item.ErrorsList.Add("More than one contact found matching with organisation");
            }
            else 
            {
                contact = allcontact.FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (contact != null)
            {
                item.AgencyId = contact.Id;
                item.AgencyReference = contact.Reference;
            }
            else
            {
                item.ErrorsList.Add("Contact not found matching with organisation");
                item.CanContinue = false;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PostCode))
        {
            item.ErrorsList.Add("Postcode is required");
            item.CanContinue = false;
        }
       
        #region " Employee Number Validation"
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.EmployeeNumber) || item.EmployeeNumber.Length < 8)
        {
            item.CanContinue = false;
            item.ErrorsList.Add("Invalid Employee Number");
        }
        else
        {
            string employeenumber = item.EmployeeNumber.Substring(0, 8);
            employee = employees.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ExternalReference) && x.ExternalReference.ToLower().StartsWith(employeenumber.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();

            if (employee != null)
            {
                item.EmployeeId = employee.Id;
                item.EmployeeExternalRef = employee.ExternalReference;

                if (company.IsPayrollEnabled && employee.PayrollGroup?.Id != null)
                {
                    item.PayrollGroupId = employee.PayrollGroup?.Id;
                    var payrollGroup = session.Query<PayrollGroup>().Where(x => x.Id == employee.PayrollGroup.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (payrollGroup != null)
                    {
                        item.Payroll = payrollGroup.Description.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

                item.StarterDeclaration = Interfaces.HMRC.StarterDeclaration.OnlyJob;
                item.TaxCode = session.Query<PayeSetting>().Single(x => x.Year == GovernmentTaxYearEndDate(DateTime.Today).Year).DefaultTaxCode;

                item.EmployeeExternalRef = item.EmployeeNumber;
                item.ChangeLogList.Add("Employee " + item.EmployeeNumber + " will be created");
                item.CanContinue = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region " Validate Contract(Assignment number) "
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ContractNumber))
        {
            item.CanContinue = false;
            item.ErrorsList.Add("Invalid Contract Number");
        }
        else
        {
            if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.ContractStartDateString, out date))
            {
                item.ContractStartDate = date;
            }

            if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.ContractEndDateString, out date))
            {
                item.ContractEndDate = date;
            }

            var contract = contracts.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ContractReference) && x.ContractReference.ToLower() == item.ContractNumber.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

            if (employee == null && contract != null)
            {
                item.ContractReference = contract.ContractReference;

                item.ErrorsList.Add("Contract can not be created because contract with reference " + contract.ContractReference + " is already assigned to other employee");
                item.CanContinue = false;
            }
            else if (contract != null)
            {
                if (contract.Employee.Id == employee.Id)
                {
                    item.ContractId = contract.Id;
                    item.ContractReference = contract.ContractReference;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.ErrorsList.Add("Contract with reference " + contract.ContractReference + " is already assigned to other employee");
                    item.CanContinue = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                item.ContractReference = item.ContractNumber;

                if (contact == null)
                {
                    item.ErrorsList.Add("Contract can not be created automatically because matching contact not found");
                    item.CanContinue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.ChangeLogList.Add("Contract " + item.ContractNumber + " will be created");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region " Parse and Assign Dates to date fields "

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.StartDateInPositionString, out date))
        {
            item.StartDateInPosition = date;
        }

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.IncrementalDateString, out date))
        {
            item.IncrementalDate = date;
        }

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.FixedTermEndDateString, out date))
        {
            item.FixedTermEndDate = date;
        }

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.WtrOptOutDateString, out date))
        {
            item.WtrOptOutDate = date;
        }

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.AdjustedServiceDateString, out date))
        {
            item.AdjustedServiceDate = date;
        }

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.NHSEntryDateString, out date))
        {
            item.NHSEntryDate = date;
        }

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.BirthDateString, out date))
        {
            item.BirthDate = date;
        }

        if (dateConvertor.TryConvertFromString(item.DateFirstHiredString, out date))
        {
            item.DateFirstHired = date;
        }
        else if (!item.EmployeeId.HasValue)
        {
            item.DateFirstHired = DateTime.Today.Date;
        }
        #endregion

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Title))
        {
            item.Title = item.Title.Replace(".", "");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.MaritalStatus))
        {
            item.MaritalStatus = "U";
        }

        item.Payroll = string.Empty;

        lineNum++;

        item.Errors = item.ErrorsList.Count > 0 ? String.Join("|", item.ErrorsList.Distinct()) : string.Empty;
        item.ChangeLog = item.ChangeLogList.Count > 0 ? String.Join("|", item.ChangeLogList) : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my, that's a lot of `#regions`s

Comment: Hi Swati, welcome to stackoverflow. There are too many `if..else` conditions in your code. Which if condition is taking long time to execute? We can not help you with your current code. I request you update your question and create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: While `Switch` statements are a lil faster than `If-Else` it generally doesn't matter. But it does matter the way you implement them. It seems like you have put a lot in just one `For-each` loop and a lot of conditions. I would say for better optimization break code in parts and implement efficient strategy using divide and conquer rule.

Comment: can we see the implementation of `TryConvertFromString` ?

Comment: Have you profiled or otherwise measured your code? We might make guesses about what takes time, but without measuring it is just guesses. you might want to take a look at [find, Fix, and Avoid Performance Problems in C#](https://michaelscodingspot.com/performance-problems-in-csharp-dotnet/)

Comment: I will have suggested replacing the foreach loop with parallel.foreach just to have a quick and dirty force multiplier, but it  probably be bad practice on a web project.

Answer (score -1):

A good rule of thumb is that if you have copy/pasted code then you should have put it in a function, you could make one function for the date checking then call that, a lot of compilers and translators will then just hold that little bit in memory and repeatedly call it rather than all the lines you have there.

for the sake of readable code, maybe each region should be a separate function?

Shift your temp employee and contact object declarations outside the loop, as it is you have a memory declaration and memory assignation in each loop, moving it outside means you just have the assignation inside the loop (the parser/translator should do this automatically in c# but not always)

Shift everything that is not unique to that particular item to outside of the loop, the taxcode year for example means for every item that hits that else conditional then you are doing a linq query. Incidentally I have noticed great speed and memory gains to be made if you use for loops instead of linq, but they are less readable.

Item.CanContinue isn't used anywhere, maybe each object could handle it's own validation or you could have a static function that checks an object for issues and adds the issues to the list.

one example:

```
bool chkStringNotNull(string data, ref item, string ErrorMsg) 
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {
        item.ErrorsList.Add(ErrorMsg);
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Of course you would need to refactor to use item as a ref.